# How do i export only the name of the columns from mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, metadata, mongodb-compass, columnheader

I am new to mongodb and my task is to export metadata about all collections in a database. I know little about shell scripting and i am not able to understand the documents provided on mongodb website.

I am using Mongodb compass 4.2.14 and though i am able to export the collection, i am not able to just export the column names.

How do i export just the column names and also how to view the metadata?

Comment: The version 4.2.14 you are referring to is that of the MongoDB database mostly, not that of the Compass. The latest Compass version is 1.28.4.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

In Compass GUI, select the Schema TAB, and click the Analyze button. This will show the data types for each field for a collection.

To get a copy of the schema, from the top-left menu, select the Collection -> Share Schema as JSON menu item. This will copy the schema to the Clipboard. You can then paste from the clipboard into any text file/editor of your choice.

Reference: [Compass - Analyze Schema](https://docs.mongodb.com/compass/current/schema/).